# Column name "descriptor" -> 'MyDAL.CompanyTable.Descriptor' hides inherited member

Tags: c#, inheritance, naming-conventions, subsonic3

I wanted to take advantage of SubSonic's default behavior to find the first non-key string column to use as the object description. Usually I just name that column description and then [bracket] it in t/sql. This time I decided to name the column "Descriptor".

That leads to this warning:

> Warning   3   'SW21Console.DAL.CompanyTable.Descriptor' hides inherited member 'SubSonic.Schema.DatabaseTable.Descriptor'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

So - just lump it and go with [Description]?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, name it something other than Descriptor - "Descriptor" is a member on the base class used by subsonic, and re-using it for this would be a Bad Idea.  You could certainly get around it with some clever tricks and use "Descriptor", but in the end that would be way more work than just using a different name (even if that means bracketing the name in the SQL)